# How to get the frame rate from h.264 video stream?

Tags: video, video-streaming, h.264

How to get frame rate and bitrate from h.264 video stream? I'm able to get width and height from SPS NAL unit but not the frame rate.

Comment: if you are talking about a file - i use GSpot

Answer (score 5):

`vui_parameters` of SPS NAL has fields: `timing_info_present_flag`, `num_units_in_tick`, `time_scale`, `fixed_frame_rate_flag` - together they define frame rate of the stream (when/if applicable).

Comment: How can one get the frame rate when `timing_info_present_flag` is false?

Comment: @bio frame rate overall is optional: sequence of H.264 encoded frames can be rateless.